# Issue with Firebase admin .listen() AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, listener, firebase-admin

I am attempting to implement the solution outlined in the following thread: [python firebase realtime listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863708/python-firebase-realtime-listener)

However, an exception is returned on this line of code:

```
a = db.reference('reference/path').listen(call_back_function)
```

**Error returned:**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 376, in listen
    session = _sseclient.KeepAuthSession(self._client.credential)
AttributeError: '_Client' object has no attribute 'credential'
```

Comment: I think that's a bug in the latest version. Can you file an issue for this on GitHub? In the meantime use an old version of the SDK (v3.x).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is not yet added at https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/.
At the moment, you can download the package directly from Github.

1. You need to remove the installed package

   `pip uninstall firebase-admin`
2. Install the package directly from github.

   `pip install git+https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python.git#egg=firebase-admin`