# Detect changes in firebase realtime database with python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have some python code running 24/7 on a server like so:

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
while True:
        result = db.child("imgPostStatus").get()

        isImageToScan = None

        for elements in result.each():
            isImageToScan = elements.val()
        if isImageToScan:
            #perform the rest of the code
            #set isImageToScan to false in the DB
```

The above code keeps fetching data from the database over and over again and only runs the rest of the code if `isImageToScan` is true. Is there a way to add a listener so that it triggers the code when there is a change to the value in the database instead of manually iterating through the loop over and over again like this?

A user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984433/python-firebase-listener-implementation) seems to have solved this using REST API, I am not familiar with REST API. How would I implement this in my code if the way mentioned in this post is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses `get`, which gets the data and immediately continues

To **listen** for data, follow the documentation on [streaming updates](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#streaming). From there:

```
def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"]) # put
    print(message["path"]) # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["data"]) # {'title': 'Pyrebase', "body": "etc..."}

my_stream = db.child("posts").stream(stream_handler)
```

This will open a single [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) connection, sending updates over HTTP.

---

Note that Firebase also has an [Admin SDK for Python](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), which also support streaming updates through its [`listen` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#firebase_admin.db.Reference.listen).