# How to listen firebase database changes in python script?

Tags: python, firebase

I want to listen to changes from the Firebase database in Python script.

What am I looking for:

- I have multiple users in my Firebase database.
- I want to notify the user that a file is available to download from Firebase.
- To verify whether the user has access to download the file, I want to use the user token in the Python script.
- Users will use their own token in the Python script.
- The Python script will be distributed to the users.

What will be the steps to follow?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can only help you solve the problems you encounter, not write code for you.

Comment: I want the steps that I have to do.

Comment: Check the stack overflow policy on how to ask a good question it might help : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do I have to run a local Python server using Flask and then create a webhook link, then post data from Firebase to the local Python server via webhook link?

Comment: To listen for changes from a Firebase database in a Python script, you can use the Firebase Realtime Database SDK for Python. Check this out https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/

Comment: Can I share that python script to the users?

Comment: Try looking at [Python-Firebase listener implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40984433/16653700).